# Using certbot DNS authorization with multiple API accounts?

Tags: ssl-certificate, certbot, digital-ocean

I'm using EFF certbot ACME client to generate a single TLS certificates on my webserver that is hosting multiple domains using Subject Alternative Names (SAN). Up until now all of the domains where hosted in a specific Digital Ocean team, and I have certbot configured with the Digital Ocean DNS plugin and a personal access token created for that team to generate a certificate with multiple domains (including wildcard domains).

Now a client wants me to also serve a domain that they want to retain full control of, so we created a new Digital Ocean team and my account where the DO personal access token was created has been given access to. Unfortunately, I also found out that personal access token are created for a team and cannot be used with another team.

I looked through the certbot docs but could not find how to configure different DO credentials for different domains for the same SAN certificate - is this even possible?

If not - what other alternatives would you suggest to implement this use case?

Comment: The plugin requires a config file with credentials, right? Specify different config files as required?

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist I'm not sure how that would work - the documentation only mentions a single config key of the token. Can you write an answer with example configuration files?

Answer (score 2):

This is apparently not supported by any built-in authenticator plugins, but can be solved by using a "manual hook" to script the challenges and there for choose for each domain being verified, the best method to generate the verification token.

I've written a manual hook script that supports verifying domains in multiple Digital Ocean teams/users, assuming you have a personal access token for each. [The script is available here: https://gist.github.com/guss77/01f095623a1d2fd00869784554d3e1a5](https://gist.github.com/guss77/01f095623a1d2fd00869784554d3e1a5).

To use it, make sure you have the Digital Ocean CLI `doctl` tool installed somewhere (and configure it in the script) and also set up your personal access tokens in the script (the script also needs `dig` and a few common POSIX shell tools that I expect to find everywhere, though may not work well outside Linux).

Then instead of using one of the `--dns*` plugins, use:

```
--preferred-challenges=dns --manual \
--manual-auth-hook /path/to/certbot-hook.sh \
--manual-cleanup-hook /path/to/certbot-hook.sh
```

When trying to authenticate, certbot will call this script to create the DNS records for each domain to be verified - for which the script will use the `doctl` tool, after scanning the list of domains available using each personal access token and choosing the correct "zone" in which to create the record.

I sometimes have issues with this approach, though, specifically around the DNS propagation time - certbot supports custom DNS propagation wait timeouts for DNS plugins but not for manual mode and there is no good way to mimic it otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this by simply specifying different configuration files.

As per the [`certbot-dns-digitalocean` plugin documentation](https://certbot-dns-digitalocean.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) the credentials are provided in an ini file:

> `--dns-digitalocean-credentials`  DigitalOcean credentials INI file. (Required)

With the ini file containing something like:

> `dns_digitalocean_token = 0000111122223333444455556666777788889999aaaabbbbccccddddeeeeffff`

If you were to create different such files for your different credentials, you could make the plugin use different credentials by specifying these different files.

Ie, something like

```
certbot certonly \
  --dns-digitalocean \
  --dns-digitalocean-credentials ~/.secrets/certbot/digitalocean-foo.ini \
  -d domain1.example
```

and

```
certbot certonly \
  --dns-digitalocean \
  --dns-digitalocean-credentials ~/.secrets/certbot/digitalocean-bar.ini \
  -d domain2.example
```

would use the credentials from two separate files.

Comment: Sorry - it wasn't made clear in my question that I need to create a single SAN certificate for all the domains. I'll fix the question. Your answer looks to be generating two different certificates.

Comment: @Guss Now, that I suspect may not be supported...